# Classification of all conjugacy classes of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$, $GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Give a classification of all conjugacy classes in the following groups.
>
> 1. $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$
> 2. $GL_2(\mathbb{Q})$

My progress so far. If the characteristic polynomial splits, the matrix will be similar to its Jordan canonical form, then there are cases where it doesn't. In $\mathbb{R}$, that's because of imaginary roots, in $\mathbb{Q}$ also because of irrational roots. But I don't know what to do next. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

You're almost done.
If $A\in GL_2(\mathbb F)$ has an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda\in\mathbb F$, then either $A\sim\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&1\\0&\lambda\end{pmatrix}$ (which gives one conjugacy class per element of $\mathbb F$) or $A\sim\begin{pmatrix}\lambda&0\\0&\lambda'\end{pmatrix}$ (which gives one conjugacy class per unordered(!) pair $\{\lambda,\lambda'\}$ of not necessarily distinct elements of $\mathbb F$).

Remains the case that $A$ has no eigenvectors. Then by picking any nonzero vector $v_1$ as first vector of a basis and $v_2=Av_1$ as second (if they were linearly dependent, then $v_1$ would be eigenvector). with respect to this basis $A$ gets the form $A\sim\begin{pmatrix}0&-\det A\\1&\operatorname{tr}A\end{pmatrix}$. Here we get one class per each quadratic polynomial $X^2-\operatorname{tr}A \cdot X+\det A$ with no root in $\mathbb F$, i.e., for each pair $(p,q)\in\mathbb F^2$ such that the discriminant $p^2-4q$ is not a square in $\mathbb F$.